# checking for an integer in a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, series

I ran into a surprising result when looking for an integer id number in a pandas column of integers where I knew the number was in the list. I've now boiled this down to a really simple test case that baffles me. I'm clearly missing something really obvious?!

Here is how I reproduced the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create two pandas objects; col_2 is an np.int64 
source_series_1 = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': ['a','b','c','d'], 'col_2':np.int64([1, 2, 3, 4])})
source_series_2 = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': ['a','b','c','d'], 'col_2':np.int64([101, 102, 103, 104])})
```

Now test membership in the these dfs:

```
# Test membership in pandas series
print(np.int64(2) in source_series_1.col_2)
print(np.int64(102) in source_series_2.col_2)
```

output:

```
True
False # ?!
```

```
# But! convert to a simple list...
print(np.int64(2) in list(source_series_1.col_2))  
print(np.int64(102) in list(source_series_2.col_2))
```

output:

```
True
True
```

I note I get the same output for both without the explicit cast:

```
print(2 in source_series_1.col_2) #True
print(102 in source_series_2.col_2) #False
```

There is clearly something incredibly simple going on that I am just missing/forgetting. I'd love to understand why source_series_2 fails the 'in' test?

Comment: When you use `in`, you are checking whether a value is in the `index` of the Series.  `102 in source_series_2.col_2.values` should return `True`

Comment: Thanks @DerekO. Yup. I actually saw that question before I posted -- but I didn't connect the dots. Sorry!

Comment: No worries! My vote to close the question is purely because the linked answer explains it best in my opinion so there's no need to repeat the answer here

Comment: happy to do so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think the issue here is with the internal working of the functions.

```
print(np.int64(2) in source_series_1.col_2)
print(np.int64(102) in source_series_2.col_2)
```

This looks at the index of the DataFrame/Series (source_series_1.col_2 or source_series_2.col_2) in your case.

Where as

```
print(np.int64(2) in list(source_series_1.col_2))  
print(np.int64(102) in list(source_series_2.col_2))
```

is explicitly list search in the values as there is no Index.

How I reached on this conclusion is that if you search for

```
print(np.int64(2) in source_series_1.col_2)
print(np.int64(2) in source_series_2.col_2)
```

You'll get

```
True
True
```

I hope this helps !

Comment: Ideally this should have raised the out of index error in the 1st case but I think it is not happening.

Comment: Ahah. I never realized it was actually looking at the index. This makes great sense. Can also fix it simply by:  `print(np.int64(102) in source_series_2.col_2.values)`. This really helps.

Comment: Thanks @Amit Gupta. I knew it was something simple! "in" looks at the index not at the values. Onward.  Also worth mentioning that `someseries.isin(target)` would be another way to solve the problem but wanted to understand why the simple case wasn't working.

Comment: Yes, I also learned a good thing from this. it was really obvious but never observed.

Answer (score 0):

pd.Series is not meant to work this way with the 'in' operator.
For example:
This works but it doesnt make sense right?

```
np.int64(1) in source_series_2.col_2
>>>True
np.int64(2) in source_series_2.col_2
>>>True
```

But if you look at the actual implementation of what you need to do, you can use this because it does an actual match on the elements.

```
getattr(source_series_2.col_2,'__eq__')(101)
```

Output:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: col_2, dtype: bool
```